# Installing from Live USB is successful, but then generic Boot Menu doesn't start the OS

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, grub-efi, boot-partition

Lenovo Thinkbook 14 given to me originally because original owner had deleted all partitions with (OEM Windows 10) and installed Linux Lite which was successful, but friend could not learn how to reinstall windows at all, gave up and gave this to me.

In his attempt to revert to windows, if I don't have the live usb in, it shows me a very generic 'Boot Menu' with two options in the window.

1. MX21
2. eMMC Card: Ramaxel 64gb

the bar on bottom of screeen only provides: [arrowkey up and down] -Move [AK left and right] -Collapse/Expand  [Enter] -Select [ESC] -Exit

Selecting either of the two options, flashes screen black, and immediately right back to this menu. So does hitting the ESC button.  Trying to get into UEFI or BIOS, hitting shift on boot, F12, ESC etc changes nothing.
Friend says that it used to have a LENOVO splash screen with prompt to hit F12 to get into Setup.  Not so anymore.  From cold off boot to this generic boot menu is 1.5 seconds.

Ok, so insert my ubuntu live disk, selecting either of the two options or esc and it boots into the OS on the USB.  I can install and told with great aplomb that it was successful, no errors but upon removal of the USB, right back to the boot menu.  Anybody have any thoughts on whats going on here?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Neither Windows nor Linux Lite are Ubuntu products, and whilst you do mention a Ubuntu live disk, it's vague with only specific details given to off-topic OSes*

Comment: The Lenovo Thinkbook 14 boots to a very generic 'Boot Menu', so it never has a chance to get to Ubuntu's grub bootloader. I don't have any experience with this laptop model, but nonetheless I am curious to know what would happen if you removed the CMOS battery for five minutes which sets the UEFI back to its default settings. Would this remove the superfluous, unwanted very generic 'Boot Menu' thereby allowing Ubuntu to boot normally?